# How to get data in stream builder with the multiple conditions/queries?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to display post with queries in Page view builder with the help of stream builder but not able to get the data with the separate function I made. I have tried calling the function in stream but then I don't get any data. how can I call the following function in stream. Or do I need to try something else instead of stream builder?

If I do this then it display the Page view builder but with no condition and fetch all the data.

```
           StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                          stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')..doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
        .collection('plans').snapshots(),
                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
                            if (!snapshot.hasData){
                              return Text(
                                          "No Data",
   );  
                               }if(snapshot.hasData){
                         
                              return PageView.builder(.........),
```

And if I call getUserPlan() then I dont get data.

```
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                              stream: getUserPlan(),
                              builder: (BuildContext context,
                                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
                                if (!snapshot.hasData){
                                  return Text(
                                              "No Data",
       );  
                                   }if(snapshot.hasData){
                             
                                  return PageView.builder(.........),
```

function getUserPlan:-   // I want to stream data with all this queries/conditions.

```
 getUserPlan() {
    List pUser = [];
     FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
        .collection('plans').where('pTimeStamp',
        isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime.now())
        .orderBy('pTimeStamp', descending: true).get().then((_){
      query().get().then((data)async{
        if (data.docs.length < 1   ) {
          print("no more Plan data");
          return;
        }
        for (var doc in data.docs) {
          CreateAccountData temp = CreateAccountData.fromDocument(doc);
          var distance = calculateDistance(
              currentUser.coordinates['latitude'],
              currentUser.coordinates['longitude'],
              temp.coordinates['latitude'],
              temp.coordinates['longitude']);
          temp.distanceBW = distance.round();
          if (pUser.any(
                (value) => value == temp.uid,
          )) {
          } else {
            if (distance <= currentUser.maxDistance && temp.uid != currentUser.uid && !temp.isBlocked){pUsers.add(temp);}
          }
        }
        if (mounted) setState(() {});

      });
    });
  }

query() {
    if (currentUser.showGender == 'everyone') {
      return docRef
          .where('age',
        isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: currentUser.ageRange['min'],
      )
          .where('age',
          isLessThanOrEqualTo:currentUser.ageRange['max'])
          .orderBy('age', descending: false).limit(30);
    } else {
      return docRef
          .where('editInfo.userGender', isEqualTo: currentUser.showGender)
          .where('age',
        isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:currentUser.ageRange['min'],
      )
          .where('age',
          isLessThanOrEqualTo: currentUser.ageRange['max'])
          .orderBy('age', descending: false).limit(30);
    }
  }
```